# How to set up google cloud speech api on a maven project on intellij

Tags: google-cloud-intellij

Hey I am a beginner can someone help me with setting up google speech-text api on a maven project on intellij?

I have pasted [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3kl9Q.png) in the pom file but it is giving me an [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXbId.png)
.
I tried looking through the documentation provided by google but I cant seem to understand what I am doing wrong.

https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/transcribe-client-libraries#client-libraries-install-java

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>oops</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>oops</name>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
<junit.version>5.9.2</junit.version>  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
      <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
      <version>20.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
      <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
      <version>20.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>libraries-bom</artifactId>
      <version>26.26.0</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-cloud-storage</artifactId>
    </dependency>



<dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
      <version>${junit.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
      <version>${junit.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.openpnp</groupId>
      <artifactId>opencv</artifactId>
      <version>4.7.0-0</version>
    </dependency>


  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.11.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>20</source>
          <target>20</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>





      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.8</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <!-- Default configuration for running with: mvn clean javafx:run -->
            <id>default-cli</id>
            <configuration>
              <mainClass>com.example.oops/com.example.oops.VideoApplication</mainClass>
              <launcher>app</launcher>
              <jlinkZipName>app</jlinkZipName>
              <jlinkImageName>app</jlinkImageName>
              <noManPages>true</noManPages>
              <stripDebug>true</stripDebug>
              <noHeaderFiles>true</noHeaderFiles>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>


  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>snapshots-repo</id>
      <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
      <releases>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>
  </repositories>



</project>
```

Comment: An error? Normally you’d tell us what the error was. Have you read the docs? https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/transcribe-client-libraries#client-libraries-install-java

Comment: StackOverflow is not a place to ask for tutorials. Anyway, your question lacks of details, you mention that it gives you an error, what error? We can't guess that. In addition don't post code as images, copy paste as text. What documentation did you read?

Comment: Im sorry im really new to this I have posted the error  as a screenshot. I read this https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/transcribe-client-libraries#client-libraries-install-java documentation and I added the dependency onto my pom file.

Answer (score 0):

The version of google cloud storage was not specified specify the latest version from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/cloud/google-cloud-storage/

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-cloud-storage</artifactId>
      <version>2.9.3</version>
</dependency>
```

[How to fix Non-resolvable import POM: com.google.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71607352/how-to-fix-non-resolvable-import-pom-com-google-cloudspring-cloud-gcp-dependen)